# SQL Group by time

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have following table in my SQL Database and need to group it by the max-value of an 5 minute period of time.

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| Path | Sample |     DateTime     |
+------+--------+------------------+
| Srv1 | 0.5    | 2014-07-04 10:48 |
| Srv1 | 0.7    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv1 | 0.9    | 2014-07-04 10:52 |
| Srv1 | 0.6    | 2014-07-04 10:54 |
| Srv2 | 8.2    | 2014-07-04 10:48 |
| Srv2 | 7.4    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv2 | 10.9   | 2014-07-04 10:52 |
| Srv2 | 9.9    | 2014-07-04 10:54 |
| Srv3 | 7.8    | 2014-07-04 10:48 |
| Srv3 | 1.3    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv3 | 5.7    | 2014-07-04 10:52 |
| Srv3 | 2.4    | 2014-07-04 10:54 |
| Srv4 | 4.2    | 2014-07-04 10:47 |
| Srv4 | 3.8    | 2014-07-04 10:49 |
| Srv4 | 5.4    | 2014-07-04 10:51 |
| Srv4 | 2.4    | 2014-07-04 10:53 |
| Srv5 | 1.6    | 2014-07-04 10:48 |
| Srv5 | 1.3    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv5 | 1.6    | 2014-07-04 10:52 |
| Srv5 | 1.3    | 2014-07-04 10:54 |
+------+--------+------------------+
```

Following table would be my goal:

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| Path | Sample |     DateTime     |
+------+--------+------------------+
| Srv1 | 0.5    | 2014-07-04 10:45 |
| Srv1 | 0.9    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv2 | 8.2    | 2014-07-04 10:45 |
| Srv2 | 10.9   | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv3 | 7.8    | 2014-07-04 10:45 |
| Srv3 | 5.7    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv4 | 6.8    | 2014-07-04 10:45 |
| Srv4 | 5.4    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
| Srv5 | 1.6    | 2014-07-04 10:45 |
| Srv5 | 1.6    | 2014-07-04 10:50 |
+------+--------+------------------+
```

I tried following code but it didn't put out the expecting result. `GROUP BY me.Path, pd.DateTime, DATEPART(mi, pd.DateTime) % 10`

My whole SQL is:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT me.Path, MAX(pd.SampleValue) AS Sample, pd.DateTime
  FROM Perf.vPerfRaw AS pd
       INNER JOIN dbo.vPerformanceRuleInstance AS pri ON pri.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId = pd.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId
       INNER JOIN dbo.vPerformanceRule AS pr ON pr.RuleRowId = pri.RuleRowId
       INNER JOIN dbo.vManagedEntity AS me ON me.ManagedEntityRowId = pd.ManagedEntityRowId
       INNER JOIN dbo.vRule AS vr ON vr.RuleRowId = pri.RuleRowId
       INNER JOIN OperationsManager.dbo.RelationshipGenericView AS rgv ON rgv.TargetObjectDisplayName = me.Path
 WHERE (pr.CounterName = '% Processor Time')
   AND (vr.RuleDefaultName = 'Processor % Processor Time Total 2003'
       OR vr.RuleDefaultName = 'Processor % Processor Time Total Windows Server 2008'
       OR vr.RuleDefaultName = 'Processor Information % Processor Time Total Windows Server 2008 R2'
       OR vr.RuleDefaultName = 'Processor Information % Processor Time Total Windows Server 2012'
       OR vr.RuleDefaultName = 'Processor Information % Processor Time Total Windows Server 2012 R2')
   AND (rgv.SourceObjectDisplayName = 'SVM')
GROUP BY me.Path, pd.DateTime, DATEPART(mi, pd.DateTime) % 10
ORDER BY me.Path
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a rigorous schema of your table and your complete query, because the names in your "examples" don't match the columns in the code you tried (which also seems to involve 2 tables `me` and `pd`), so I'm not sure I understand what you want/tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `pd.DateTime` in the selected columns AND the group by clause, so you're not actually performing any aggregation.

There are many ways to do this, some better than others depending on your data, but try this :

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    me.Path, 
    MAX(pd.SampleValue) AS Sample, 
    DATEADD(MI, -(DATEPART(MI, pd.DateTime) % 5), pd.DateTime) AS PeriodStart
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY me.Path, DATEADD(MI, -(DATEPART(MI, pd.DateTime) % 5), pd.DateTime)
ORDER BY me.Path
```

Note that this will only work if seconds in your datetime values are always 0. You'll need an additionnal `DATEADD` to offset them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the remainder operator. You want integer division.

```
select [path], MAX(sample),
    convert(time,dateadd(minute,convert(int,(CONVERT(decimal(9,4), datetime) % 1)/0.003472)*5,0)) 
from yourdata
GROUP BY Path,  convert(time,dateadd(minute,convert(int,(CONVERT(decimal(9,4), datetime) % 1)/0.003472)*5,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT    Path, MAX(Sample), DATEADD(MINUTE, (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, Created)%5 BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 0 ELSE 5 END)-(DATEPART(MINUTE, Created))%5, Created) AS NewDate
FROM      ...
GROUP BY  Path, DATEADD(MINUTE, (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, Created)%5 BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 0 ELSE 5 END)-(DATEPART(MINUTE, Created))%5, Created)
ORDER BY  Path
```

Answer (score 0):

The one problem with the existing answers is that none will be able to use indices, due to the use of functions on the "source" columns.  You might be able to get better performance via the simple expedient of defining an inline range-query table, as with a recursive CTE.  Something like this:

```
WITH Time_Slice AS (SELECT startedAt, endedBy
                FROM (VALUES(CAST('20140704' AS DATETIME2), 
                             DATEADD(minute, 5, CAST('20140704' AS DATETIME2)))) a(startedAt, endedBy)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT endedBy, DATEADD(minute, 5, endedBy)
                FROM Time_Slice
                WHERE endedBy < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST('20140704' AS DATETIME2)))

SELECT *
FROM Time_Slice
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36330/0)</kbd>

Obviously, this needs to be generated over a specific range - if you're only selecting results from a given range you can use that as the starting/ending values; otherwise, it looks like getting the `MIN()` value in the starting section works, and running up to the current time.

You can then reference this as a regular table, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT me.Path, MAX(pd.SampleValue) AS Sample, ts.startedAt
FROM Perf.vPerfRaw AS pd
INNER JOIN dbo.vManagedEntity AS me ON me.ManagedEntityRowId = pd.ManagedEntityRowId
INNER JOIN Time_Slice AS ts ON pd.DateTime >= ts.startedAt AND pd.DateTime < ts.endedBy
GROUP BY me.Path, ts.startedAt
ORDER BY me.Path
```